# clarification of the term "is on the classpath"

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

When the phrase "`is on the classpath`" is used in boot documentation, can I get a precise meaning for this for a linux person building a spring boot maven project?

1. it is not clear about the context in time: is it talking about compile or run time or repackage time or what?
2. does it mean that a jar/manifest  is in a subdirectory of the current project directory such as the target/...classes
3. does it mean that the jar is in the pom
4. for a newbie, I read the wikipedia and oracle explanations but this seems to mean something different or it means that i should be born with the knowledge of some sort of modifications to the classpath made by maven during the build process.
5. or what about during run time for a repackaged jar?
6. Is there anybody who would have mercy on a newbie and help me on the term?

Comment: I think this literally means that a specific folder needs to be in your CLASSPATH environment variable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Can't *you* be more precise about which instance of "is on the classpath" you are asking about? I'm sure it can mean different things depending on the context/chapter that you are talking about; i.e. one time it may refer to packaging time and another time it may refer to runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer your questions:

1. You can have a compile classpath as well a runtime classpath (Maven also has a test classpath). They can be different, so it depends on the context, which one is meant.
2. Technically it doesn't matter, what the directory structure is, since you can add every directory on your disk to your classpath.
3. If you use Maven, then only JARs, that are defined in the POM, are automatically added to the compile classpath (which is also used for packaging).
4. Maven uses different classpaths during the build. E.g. for compiling it uses all dependencies in provided or compile scope and adds them to the classpath. For testing, additional dependencies in the test scope are added to the classpath to compile and execute tests.